# Automation for Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, automation

I am working on a Windows Phone with PhoneGap application wherein after each time I run the app on emulator I have to fill the username password for the application. Is there any easy way e.g with power that in one click it will fill the username password and click sign in button for me?
Kind of like automation testing.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 professional.

Comment: So why don't you harcode those values wherever necessary, and then after testing put the appropriate values?

Comment: because its sso page that I cant control

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do that with the Emulator itself.